# How to manage access rights permission on Subversion using command prompt or other GUI tool on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

I have installed Subversion Edge which is an opensource integrated package for Subversion on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

Recently, we have got an error on apache installed by subversion edge, and our Subversion Edge control center is now not accessible, and giving us a internal server error. (this is not a problem because we are still able to checkout / commit on created repository. and browse it using view vc and svn). So we're unable to use a GUI provided by Subversion Edge to manage the stack.

Now because its control panel is not opening, I'm unable create new repository, or add new users or update access rights/permission for users or groups created earlier.

Is there any way (may be from command prompt) or other GUI tools to manage this until the server error is addressed?

Comment: Have you restarted Subversion Edge (console)?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't solved the error.

Comment: What does that mean? You can call the console? Have you checked the log files?

Comment: Tried to fix the error but unable to get it in working condition. Checked log files too. No clue why its' not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access Permissions can be manually edited in a text file "svn_access_file" located at \data\conf folder of the csvn installation.

Still, don't know how to create new repository or add new user manually.

Comment: To add or delete users: `htpasswd -b \data\conf\svn-auth-file username password`

Answer (score 1):

Install a command-line SVN client, such as [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/). Read [An Administrator's Toolkit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk) section in *Version Control with Subversion*.

Comment: I installed this, but documentation is very poor for commands on windows os :(

Comment: It implements all the 'reference' SVN client commands as defined in [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

How about reporting the problem with the console so you can get it working again?  I would recommend following the ManualUpgrade instructions on this page:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/ManualUpgrade

Comment: There is a discussion forum here - http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=3  Post details, including whatever is in your console log file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Respective Repository location and there will be a passwd file under conf like
`/data/Repository_Name/conf/passwd`

For example, if u want to give permission for given Repository_Name repository follow below steps:

1. Go to the location to find the passwd file
2. Make an entry the repective user id and cretae a password for him.
3. Send the credential details to the user and let him try accessing.

Its Done for Granting access.

Thanks,
Manas Kumar Panigrahi,
US Technologies,Bangalore.